How can I make a Frame with a label in the border in .Net Maui?
How can I make a Frame like that, so the name/label is in the border using .NET MAUI and XAML?
It should look like in the following picture:
Frame
I already tried to do it somehow manually, by trying to set a label at this position, but I couldn't achieve the look.

Like this No.8? https://github.com/shawyunz/XampleControl.
Just a heads-up, if you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead of Frame, my code is just Xamarin version.

Yes, that's it, thank you.

Just put a Border (or Frame) with a Label inside a Grid. E.g.,
<Grid>
    <Border/>
    <Label Text="Colors" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
</Grid>

By putting Border and Label in a Grid, they will overlay each other. From here, you can manipulate things such as Margin, Padding, TranslateX, TranslateY to precisely align the components relative to each other.
Here, I take things one step further by putting it inside a ContentView and adding ContentPresenter making a new component that functions like a Border. The user can supply their own content to be wrapped inside the custom Border.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Maui.StackOverflow.BorderLabel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Border
                    Margin="10,10,10,10"
                    Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    Stroke="Black"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <Border
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    Stroke="Transparent"
                    TranslationX="30"
                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Label
                        Padding="10,0,10,0"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Colors"
                        VerticalOptions="Start" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>

